# Apach Tomcat - Disable file processing outside document root directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat, tomcat6

Is there a setting in Apache Tomcat to restrict file access outside the document root directory? Apache httpd analogue is `AllowOverride None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe SecurityManager is what I need:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/security-manager-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

Use below as first directory directive in Apache httpd.conf file.

`<Directory />
   Options None
   AllowOverride None
   Order deny,allow
   deny from all
 </Directory>`

This restricts file access to any page in server.
After this grant access to allowed Document root.

Comment: I'm using Apache Tomcat, there is no httpd.conf file.